# Why is an element not printing?

Tags: python, list

I am learning the list and list assignments and using while and for loops with lists. I wrote the following code just to test my understanding.

```
I=[1,4, 7, 6, 7,8,9]
IU=I

while IU !=[]:
    print ('I: ',I)
    print('IU :' ,IU)
    for i in I:
        print(i)
        if i*i<=36:
            IU.remove(i)
            print(IU)
    if i>=9:
        break
```

This gives the following output:

```
I:  [1, 4, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9]
IU : [1, 4, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1
[4, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9]
7
6
[4, 7, 7, 8, 9]
8
9
```

My understanding is that it would print `4` after it removed `1` from `IU`. However it is not printing `4`. Any hints on why this is happening?

Comment: Please specify your language on the tags.

Comment: `IU=I` this doesn't create new list, you can use `IU=I[:]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Issue

The issued line is `IU=I`

This line does not create a new list `IU`. Python creates a reference 'IU' to the original list `I`, which means `IU` and `I` point to the same list. Thus, when you remove `4` from your `I`, `IU` get affected too.

##### Solution

There are different ways of copying of `I`. For example, you can

```
IU = [_ for _ in I]
```

Or

```
IU = I.copy()
```

Or

```
IU = I[:]
```

##### demo

Here is a demo show the difference

```py
L = [1,2]
Ref = L
Cpy = L.copy()

L.append(3)
print(Ref)
print(Cpy)
```

- Output

  ```
  [1, 2, 3]
  [1, 2]
  ```

Comment: Another efficient list copy method is to use slicing, as: `copy = list_[:]`.

Comment: @S3DEV, Thanks for the reminder. That's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see 4 printed because when the program removed 1 initially, the loop pointer i was pointing to 1, and so, once 1 got removed, the i pointer moved to the next element, 4. And at the end of the loop, since the for loop goes over to the next element (i++ that we do in c++), it points at 7 at the starting of next iteration.
Hope I could solve your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

List in python is implemented using **Dynamic Array**

Here, after the removal of 1 from the list, the list on the left moves backward(not exactly but somewhat similar), so `i` now points to 4.

Now `i` gets incremented, thus now `i` points to the next memory location.

Please check the [link](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/) to see how the list gets implemented inside python.